# Rails: Confirm pop-up before saving to database only if checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, confirm

I have a following problem:

Inside a form for a new project on `projects/new` page there is a checkbox which is resposible for toggling `is_public` attribute of project. I would like to provide user a pop-up javascript confirmation window before creating new project but only if this particular checkbox is checked.

So far I've been trying to do it like this:

```
<%= labelled_form_for @project do |f| %>
...
<%= f.check_box :is_public %>
...
<%= submit_tag 'create', :confirm => params[:project][:is_public] == '1' ? "Are you sure you want to create public project?" : nil  %>
```

But because `create` action is not executed until this moment, `params[:project][:is_public]` do not exist and thus this solution does not work.

I've been thinking about using `jquery` to find out whether this checkbox is checked, but I don't know how I would pass obtained `jquery` variable to rails.

**Edit**

Here's the final implementation.

```
$(function(){
  $('#new_project').on('submit.confirm', function(){
    if ($('#project_is_public').prop( "checked" )) {
      if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to create this project as public?")){
        $(this).removeAttr('data-submitted');
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

`submitted` data attribute (which was kind of preventing multiple form submissions) blocked the possibility of submitting the form again after clicking on `cancel` button for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm in form submit ..

for this you need to validate using jquery form submit
for example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form_id').submit(function(){
   if($('#my_check_box_id').is(":checked")) {
     message = confirm("Are you sure to make this project public?");
      if(message) {
        return true;
      } else {
       return false;
      }
   } else {
     return true;
   }
});
});
```

Hope this will help you :)

**Edit**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_id').submit(function(){
       if($('#my_check_box_id').prop( "checked" )) {
         message = confirm("Are you sure to make this project public?");
          if(message) {
            return true;
          } else {
           return false;
          }
       } else {
         return true;
       }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks a lot! Gotta learn some more jquery, started off this week ;) I have one more question tough - can i make it possible to post form  on a second submission, that is when user clicks cancel for the first time on a confirmation box and afterwards unchecks the checkbox and clicks on submit button again? Right now, when I click cancel and try to submit something again, nothing happens.

Comment: i have added checking with prop of element. can u plz check and reply

Comment: Unfortunately, changing to `prop` didn't give any results, thanks for the help anyway ;)

Comment: Edited my answer and added solution to the problem previously described above.